# Will Ubuntu work on my old laptop running Windows 10?

Tags: lenovo, amd-processor

I was wondering if it is possible to repurpose this ancient computer with a version of ubuntu?

```
BrandLenovo
CPU2.1-GHz AMD Accelerated Processor A6-4455M
Card Slots2-1 card reader
Display Size14
Graphics CardAMD Radeon HD 7520G Graphics
Hard Drive Size500GB
Hard Drive Speed5,400rpm
Hard Drive TypeSATA Hard Drive
Native Resolution1366x768
Operating SystemWindows 8
Optical DriveNone
Optical Drive Speedn/a
Ports (excluding USB)USB 2.0, Headphone/Mic, HDMI, Ethernet, USB 3.0
RAM4GB
Size13.25 x 9.5 x 0.33-0.83 inches
Touchpad Size4.25 x 2.75 inches
USB Ports3
Wi-Fi802.11b/g/n
```

Comment: Multiple versions of Ubuntu have different Desktop Environments, and most use less RAM than the GNOME Shell desktop standard in Ubuntu. See https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours and https://itsfoss.com/which-ubuntu-install/

Answer (score 1):

The best way to answer to this question is creating a USB bootable drive with Ubuntu and make a test from the live system (=not installing anything).

Read the official guide here

> https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows